# How can I inherit bearer token from collection? (POSTMAN, Golang RESTAPI)

Tags: rest, go, jwt, postman

I am able to verify the JWT Token, by manually setting each individual request with the bearer token, but whenever I set them to inherit auth from parent, it returns `Unauthorized`, it says clearly that it's taking the auth from the name of the collection, and I've set the collection to the bearer token.

Here is the JWTMiddleware:

```
func JWTMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        authHeader := strings.Split(r.Header.Get("Authorization"), "Bearer ")
        if len(authHeader) != 2 {
            fmt.Println("Malformed token")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            w.Write([]byte("Malformed Token"))
        } else {
            jwtToken := authHeader[1]
            token, err := jwt.Parse(jwtToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
                if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
                    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
                }
                return []byte(os.Getenv("JWT_SECRET")), nil
            })

            if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && token.Valid {
                ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "props", claims)

                next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
            } else {
                fmt.Println(err)
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
                w.Write([]byte("Unauthorized"))
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Here is how the token is generated:

```
func generateJWT() (JWTToken, error) {
    signingKey := []byte(os.Getenv("JWT_SECRET"))
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
        "exp":    time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 1 * 1).Unix(),
    })
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString(signingKey)
    return JWTToken{tokenString}, err
}
```

Here is how my routes are structured:

```
var Routes = router.RoutePrefix{
    "/generate",
    []router.Route{
        router.Route{
            "gen_token",
            "GET",
            "",
            gen_token,
            false,
        },  
        router.Route{
            "testToken",
            "GET",
            "/test",
            testToken,
            true,
        },
    },
}
```

I am considering setting a global variable that I can set as the token for testing purposes, what would the solution be?